# python and shapely for to find wrong features in the shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, python-2.7, shapely, fiona

I created a python script using Fiona and shapely where I can find same values between two shapefiles in the specific field (myfield) for any of two shapefiles.

If I use next snippet code:

```
for p2 in input2:
    for p1 in file1features:
       if p2['properties']['myfield'] == p1['properties']['myfield']:
```

the script works fine and I got a new shapefile where it has only the features where there is some value. However, it doesn't work if I want to take wrong features for different field values.

For example, when I use:

```
p2['properties']['myfield'] != p1['properties']['myfield']
```

then it takes all values from the shapefile.

Comment: What do `p2` is? A feature or something else? I don't know why you didn't use `p2['myfield']` instead of `p2['properties']['myfield']` for evaluating the field 'myfield': what do `'properties'` is?

Comment: I can't figure out how to edit this to makes sense in English. Please make an attempt at proper capitalization and punctuation, so we can understand how to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This question concerns how to do a difference operation between two sets of vector features `A` and `B`.

#### A [not in] B

```
import fiona
# open datasets input2 and file1features
# ...
for p2 in input2:
    for i, p1 in enumerate(file1features):
       if p2['properties']['myfield'] == p1['properties']['myfield']:
           break
    #do something such as write feature p1
    #shpout.write(p1) # pseudocode
```

#### (A [not in] B) [and] (B [not in] A)

Also called the symmetric difference

```
# open datasets input2 and file1features
# ...
for p2 in input2:
    for i, p1 in enumerate(file1features):
       if p2['properties']['myfield'] == p1['properties']['myfield']:
           break
    #do something such as write feature p1
    #shpout.write(p1) # pseudocode

for p1 in file1features:
    for i, p2 in enumerate(input2):
       if p2['properties']['myfield'] == p1['properties']['myfield']:
           break
    #do something such as write feature p2
    #shpout.write(p2) # pseudocode
```

Comment: yes Mr.Byers that good but how to take in the new shapefile the wrong features ?

Comment: why not work != ?